# How to get dynamic url of file uploaded to sharepoint using python?

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

My code does following tasks on daily basis:

1. Create a date folder on sharepoint.DONE
2. Create a category folder in the date folder of sharepoint. DONE
3. Upload a file in respective category folder. DONE

**4. Find the url of file. PENDING**

5. Send the url on email. DONE

   ```
    def upload_files(base_url, site, access_token, fileName, filePath, fileFolderUrl):
        try:
            fileHandle = open(filePath, 'rb')

            #fileFolderUrl = f'Shared Documents/Output/{subFolder}'
            requestFileUploadUrl = f"{base_url}/{site}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{fileFolderUrl}')/Files/add(url='{fileName}',overwrite=true)"

            headers = {
               'Accept':'application/json; odata=verbose',
               'Content-Type':'application/json; odata=verbose',
               'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)
           }
            uploadFileResult = requests.post(requestFileUploadUrl, headers=headers, data=fileHandle)
            if uploadFileResult.status_code == 200:
                return "success"
            else:
                return "failure"
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in uploading files to sharepoint:{e}")
            return "error"
   ```

Can someone please help me understand the process to obtain the url of this file that I am required to upload in dynamically created folders on sharepoint using python3+?
So,the structure is : SharedDocuments/Output/Today's Date/CategoryA/file.xlsx

Comment: i did not understand. if you're able to upload to files to the folder. why cannot get the url? you already know the path and file name. anything I missed?

Comment: I am using sharepoint api to upload files and I need to share the url with user to view in browser.
The url to be shared with user will be different and while using API, the method is different.

Comment: Is it sharing link?

Comment: I have updated upload_file code in question above for clarity.

It needs to share link of file path but not doing as yet because I am unable to get link.

The Sharepoint API Documentation is as follows:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/determine-sharepoint-rest-service-endpoint-uris?tabs=http

Comment: @HobbyCoder, did you ever get the  answer to this? I'm in the same boat.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to create the URL manually as you already know the url, the site and the name of the file.

I figure out that you can create the link to share a file with this pattern :
`<base_url>/<site>/<FileFolderUrl>/<File>?&web=1`

For example : `https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Documents%20partages/testing.jpg?&web=1`

It works only for people that already have access it.

I have not yet tested in an automatic solution but only by hand in an empirical way

Comment: Sometime the path has special characters in it such as spaces or some brackets or hyphen. That would create problem in generating the path and hence I was looking for a generalized solution through Sharepoint API.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a long while but was scrolling through it today and thought of answering it. Hope it can be helpful to someone in the future.

```
    def get_out_file_url(base_url, site, access_token, file_folder, fileName):
       """
       These are random examples of file_folder and base_url
       file_folder = 'Shared Documents/Output/Dated/Category'
       base_url = 'https://company.sharepoint.com'
       """
       requestFileGetUrl = f'{base_url}/sites/{site}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(\'' + fileUrl + '/'+ '\')/files?$filter'
       headers = {
               'Accept':'application/json; odata=verbose',
               'Content-Type':'application/json; odata=verbose',
               'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)
           }
       getFileResult = requests.get(requestFileGetUrl, headers=headers)
       values = getFileResult.json()
       fileData = values['d']['results']
       for key in fileData:
           if key['Name'] == fileName:
               fileURLLink = key['ServerRelativeUrl']
               fileCreatedTime = key['TimeCreated']
               fileLastModified = key['TimeLastModified']
               fileNewUrl = base_url + urllib.parse.quote(fileURLLink)
               return fileNewUrl
       else:
           return file_folder
```